# Add _id when ensuring index?

Tags: mongodb

I am building a webapp using Codeigniter (PHP) and MongoDB.
I am creating indexes and have one question.

If I am querying on three fields (_id, status, type) and want to
create an index do I need to include _id when ensuring the index like this:

```
db.comments.ensureIndex({_id: 1, status : 1, type : 1});
```

or will this due?

```
db.comments.ensureIndex({status : 1, type : 1});
```

Answer (score -4, accepted):

You don't need to implicitly create index on the _id field, it's done automatically. See the [mongo documentation](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Indexes):

> The _id Index
>
> For all collections except capped collections, an index is automatically created for the _id field. This index is special and cannot be deleted. The _id index enforces uniqueness for its keys (except for some situations with sharding).

Comment: Yes, but when I create a compond index isn´t needed then?

Comment: @pangabiMC: That's true of the `_id` field, and useful if you're only querying on _id.  The original question was about a compound index for queries searching on _id and two other fields.  @JonathanClark: if _id is part of the search criteria and you are using a compound index, you **do** want to include _id.

Comment: Yeah I've missed that it was a compound index so my answer is practically useless. I'd remove it if I could...

Answer (score 5):

You would need to explicitly include `_id` in your `ensureIndex` call if you wanted to include it in your compound index.  But because filtering by `_id` already provides selectivity of a single document that's very rarely the right thing to do.  I think it would only make sense if your documents are very large and you're trying to use [covered indexes](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Retrieving+a+Subset+of+Fields#RetrievingaSubsetofFields-CoveredIndexes).

Answer (score 4):

MongoDB will currently only use [one index per query](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Indexing+Advice+and+FAQ#IndexingAdviceandFAQ-Oneindexperquery.) with the exception of `$or` queries.  If your common query will always be searching on those three fields (_id, status, type) then a compound index would be helpful.

From within the DB shell you can use the [explain()](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Explain) command on your query to get information on the indexes used.

Answer (score 0):

_id is unique, and by default an index is created on _id field. Given _id is unique, you would never need to query on multiple fields if query includes "_id" as that result in single document.

From: [MongoDB documentation](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v4.4/indexes/)

> Default _id Index MongoDB creates a unique index on the _id field
> during the creation of a collection. The _id index prevents clients
> from inserting two documents with the same value for the _id field.
> You cannot drop this index on the _id field.